# Content editor deleting articles, SQL Server implementation

Tags: sql-server

basically I am managing a news website which scrapes articles. Each time I scrape an article I add it to a database called Scrapercontent. An issue arose, wherein the content editor deleted some articles because they didn't want them to be displayed. However because the scraper doesn't know which articles were deleted, it just fetches the same articles again and reposts them to the Scrapercontent table on the next run. I want to avoid this reposting to the table of these same articles that the editor doesn't like.

My idea was to create another table and put all the articles there as well. That way since articles don't get deleted by the editor from this other table, I can check an incoming article against this "other" table to see if it had ever existed at some point in time. Below is an implementation but it is not good... i'm working on getting the implementation correct.

My idea is this, Everytime I get an article, I don't know if it is "good" or "bad" where bad means it was previously deleted. So, the process is

article ->  check if it is in the other "checking table"

-> if it does not exist in the "checking table"  then

->  post the article to both the "checking table" and the Scrapercontent table

Will this work and can someone give me the SQL to do it?

I use the column named a_text to see if something is already in the table or not. I am just seeing if the text that is fetched has already been fetched before or not since two articles will only have the same text if they are the same article.

Does SQL support an if then statement like:

```
If NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT *
FROM checktble
WHERE a_text = %s)''', (a_text))(
THEN INSERT INTO SCRAPERCONTENT (a_text, a_link,... etc.) VALUES (%s,%s... etc.) etc.0
```

?

Comment: Why not simply add a field `publish` that by default is set to true. If an editor does not want an article published, the field will be set to false.

Comment: Why not simply add a `IsDeleted` flag against the URL

Comment: the reason is because i would like to do it entirely from the backend w/ out any interaction w/ the front end. though i agree this is the easiest way

Comment: @Timtam - Your editors delete the content from the front end, right? If I were you, I'd simply change the logic from deleting to something different. You'd have to change things even with your approach (which would be a lot more cumbersome).